# httpd cannot be restarted due to mod_jk.so not mapped

Tags: apache, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I recently had installed Coldfusion 10 in an amazon box. However when i try to restart the httpd it throws error that httpd cannot be restarted since the mod_jk.so cannot be mapped.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the similar problem. The solution is to disable SELinux.

This helped me: http://www.xcnetwork.com/selinux-prevents-apache-from-starting-mod_jk.jsp

Comment: Simply disabling SELinux might not be a solution (or at least, not a _secure_ one) - finding out how to correct the configuration is better - which [this page](http://www.laliluna.de/articles/2008/09/14/apache_tomcat_mod_jk_selinux.html) appears to do.

Comment: @PeterBoughton: I am afraid that suggestion not working for me. I had to turn of the selinux.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you did not _have_ to turn off SELinux; rather you just need to find the appropriate config changes to get mod_jk working. Again, SELinux is a security module, disabling entire security modules is generally not secure, and recommending it as a solution (as opposed to a temporary debugging step) is probably not a responsible thing to do.